# Read multiple CSV files with separator in R

Tags: r, list, csv, readr

I'm trying to read 145 CSV. The idea then is to keep just the first row of each of them. I was able to find this suggestion on [a blog:](https://blog.exploratory.io/how-to-read-multiple-excel-or-csv-files-together-42af5d314a10) about how to read them.

```
library(readr)
files <- list.files(path = "~/Dropbox/Data/multiple_files", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
tbl <- sapply(files, read_csv, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

But the columns of my csv are separated by `|` and I have not been able to find how to read them using the separator.

How should I include the separator in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: [`readr::read_delim(..., delim="|")`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) or (base R) [`read.delim(..., sep="|")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) or `read.table(..., header=TRUE, sep="|")`.

Comment: So that would make your command `sapply(files, readr::read_delim, delim="|", simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows(.id = "id")` (or similar based on which function you choose).